# Convert small numbers to a scale from 0 to 10

Tags: python, math, scale

I have a list of urls->small numbers. numbers represents the importance of each URL

```
url, value
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00212
https://mywebsite.com/p/2, 0.00208
https://mywebsite.com/p/3, 0.00201
https://mywebsite.com/p/4, 0.00138
https://mywebsite.com/p/5, 0.00067
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00001
...
```

let's say the sum of values = 1
I would like to represent those number within a scale of 0-10 and maintaining a kind of ratio difference between numbers

```
url, value, scaled_value
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00212, 10
https://mywebsite.com/p/2, 0.00208, 9
https://mywebsite.com/p/3, 0.00201, 9
https://mywebsite.com/p/4, 0.00138, 6
https://mywebsite.com/p/5, 0.00067, 3
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00001, 1
...
```

something like this (I don't know if the ratio difference here is maintained tho)
any one can help with the maths ?
thanks

#Update

thanks to @annZen help, I tried two approach, but the results are different I don't know why. if someone can help ?

[image]

here are the two formulas I used :

```
res1 = round(x*9/maxpri)+1
res2 = round(((x-minpri)/(maxpri-minpri))*10, 2)
```

Comment: You have said scale of 0 to 10, but your two `res1` formula gives values from 1 to 10.

Comment: thanks @alaniwi do you think this alone can explain the huge difference in the numbers ? I mean the order still the same but the values are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as p:
    lst = p.read().splitlines() # List all the lines of the file

lst2 = [float(i.split(', ')[1]) for i in lst[1:]] # List all the floats

num = [round(a*9/max(lst2))+1 for a in lst2] # List all the scaled numbers

for i,(l,n) in enumerate(zip(lst,['scaled_value']+num)):
    lst[i] = f"{l}, {n}" # Add the 'scaled_value' column

with open('file.txt', 'w') as p:
    p.write('\n'.join(lst)) # Write the updated data into the file
```

Before:

```
url, value
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00212
https://mywebsite.com/p/2, 0.00208
https://mywebsite.com/p/3, 0.00201
https://mywebsite.com/p/4, 0.00138
https://mywebsite.com/p/5, 0.00067
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00001
```

After:

```
url, value, scaled_value
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00212, 10
https://mywebsite.com/p/2, 0.00208, 10
https://mywebsite.com/p/3, 0.00201, 10
https://mywebsite.com/p/4, 0.00138, 7
https://mywebsite.com/p/5, 0.00067, 4
https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00001, 1
```

---

---

---

UPDATE:

The part of my code that does the converting is:

```
num = [round(a*9/max(lst2))+1 for a in lst2]
```

where `lst2` is simply the list of floats extracted from the file. You updated the question for me to explain the difference between

```
res1 = round(x*9/maxpri)+1
res2 = round(((x-minpri)/(maxpri-minpri))*10, 2)
```

Lets first see then in my list comprehension:

```
num1 = [round(x*9/max(lst2))+1 for x in lst2]
num2 = [round(((x-min(lst2))/(max(lst2)-min(lst2)))*10, 2) for x in lst2]
print(num1)
print(num2)
```

Output:

```
[10, 10, 10, 7, 4, 1]
[10.0, 9.81, 9.48, 6.49, 3.13, 0.0]
```

The first clearest difference is that i rounded my answer to the nearest integer. Without it, it would be:

```
num1 = [round(x*9/max(lst2), 2)+1 for x in lst2]
num2 = [round(((x-min(lst2))/(max(lst2)-min(lst2)))*10, 2) for x in lst2]
print(num1)
print(num2)
```

Output:

```
[10.0, 9.83, 9.53, 6.86, 3.84, 1.04]
[10.0, 9.81, 9.48, 6.49, 3.13, 0.0]
```

The values are now very close, but there's one more thing. My code assumes that the minimum value for the scaled values is `1`, because I saw in your post `https://mywebsite.com/p/1, 0.00001, 1`. I now realize that you stated 0-10, not 1-10. So that another is to change the `9` (10-1=9) to a `10`(10-0=10), and removing the `+1`:

```
round(x*9/max(lst2), 2)+1
round(x*10/max(lst2), 2)
```

---

```
num1 = [round(x*10/max(lst2), 2) for x in lst2]
num2 = [round(((x-min(lst2))/(max(lst2)-min(lst2)))*10, 2) for x in lst2]
print(num1)
print(num2)
```

Output:

```
[10.0, 9.81, 9.48, 6.51, 3.16, 0.05]
[10.0, 9.81, 9.48, 6.49, 3.13, 0.0]
```

Still a little different, that's because I assumed the minimum value in your column is `0`, because you didn't show your whole array. But in this case, it's `0.00001`. So, go with:

```
num = [round(((x-min(lst2))/(max(lst2)-min(lst2)))*10, 2) for x in lst2]
```

#### Summary: My code assumed that you wanted the numbers scaled from 1 to 10, instead of 0 to 10, and my code assumed that the minimum value for your data is 0, which might not be the case.

Comment: hey @annZen thanks for your answer, I tried this approach, what do you think about it ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range

Comment: @DanyM Actually, the method i used was the same logic :)

Comment: yes @annZen but I don't get the same results, I've updated the thread with my results,please tell me your thoughts

Comment: Sure, just give me a minute.

Comment: @DanyM Updated.

Comment: very clear @annZen, thanks so much. where can we follow you ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get the last part?

Comment: oh sorry, the question was about where we can find you to discuss further, don't mind, I saw that you have  a facebook group and a youtube channel :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217188/discussion-between-dany-m-and-ann-zen).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a definite ratio difference between the numbers, you can set the smallest number to `1` then have every other number set to `num/smallest`.

The problem with this approach is that it does not guarantee that every URL is set to a number from `0 - 10`. In the above example, it would set the numbers to `212, 208, 201, 138, 67, and 1` respectively.

If you really need to set *every* number to be between a certain specified range, you first set the smallest URL to have importance `0`, and the largest URL to have importance `10`. Then, all the other points would lie on a line with slope `(max value - min value)/10`. The below picture showcases this concept:

[image]

In this picture, the y-values of the points represent their URL value, and the x-coordinates represent the points' importance.

Comment: hey @Telescope thanks for your answer, I tried this approach, what do you think about it ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range

Comment: That approach follows similar logic to my approach. I think it'll work great for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for production code, then I suggest `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` for sake of code that is easy to read when you come back to it later. For example:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

scaled_field_name = 'scaled_value'

with open('input.csv') as fin:
    csvin = DictReader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    rows = list(csvin)

values = [float(row['value']) for row in rows]
min_value = min(values)
max_value = max(values)
for row, value in zip(rows, values):
    scaled = 10 * (value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
    row[scaled_field_name] = str(round(scaled))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csvout = DictWriter(fout, csvin.fieldnames + [scaled_field_name])
    csvout.writerows(rows)
```

*(Note: it will not write spaces after the commas, but that should be normal for CSV.)*